# What ARM compiler version is needed for attribute(noinline) support?

Tags: c, assembly, arm, armcc, gcc-extensions

I'm not sure how to find out what version of ARM compiler(armcc) is required for any given attribute to be supported.

For example `__atribute__((noinline))`?

See 
http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124975804.htm

Comment: Failing a useful answer, there's always "manually dig through [all of the old compiler user guides and/or release notes](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.set.swdev/index.html)"... (and if you find yourself back beyond RVDS 4.0, you've probably gone too far)

Comment: But I'm building which uses different versions of armcc :(

Answer (score 3):

To address the titular question directly, the earliest version of armcc for which `__attribute__((noinline))` is supported is [version 3.0](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0205g/Cacdcghf.html#CIAGHFBA). I found that out the hard way, though; I don't know of any quick-reference for which versions introduced particular features.

Comment: I've sometimes put code on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ and flipped through old gcc versions to find when something was first supported.  (From gcc 4.4 to 6.1 currently.)  Also, if a clang version doesn't support it, you know that whatever version of `__GNUC__` and `__GNUC_MINOR__` it defines isn't high enough to include that feature.